# OpenLayers 3でマーカーを表示

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers 3でol.geom.Pointが示す位置にマーカーを表示しようとしていますが、意図した位置に表示されません。
以下のように記述しましたが、どうやら[0,0]の位置に表示されているようです。
ol.geom.Pointが示す位置にマーカーを表示するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

```
var pos = map.getView().getCenter();
var point = new ol.geom.Point(pos, 'XY');
var pointer = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: point
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 1],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
        opacity: 0.85,
        src: 'data/marker.png'
    }))
});

pointer.setStyle(iconStyle);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [pointer]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Comment: このコードにはmapとviewを生成する部分が無いのでなんとも言えませんが、viewを設定していなければ初期値は0,0なのは仕様通りだと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。viewのcenterは[139.699103, 35.659528]としており、地図はその地点を表示しています。実はmapの生成の部分とマーカーの表示部分は関数が別となっていて、同じ処理内に入れると意図した位置に表示され、別関数に分けると[0,0]の位置になるという挙動となっていることが分かりました。別関数に分けたときに何かミスをしていると思うのでその観点で調べてみます。

Comment: 一度parseFloatしてからpointを作るといいかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapとviewの作成を埋めて動くものをつくりました。これで絵は出ましたよ。
一応中身を説明すると、mapのbaseはOpenStreetMapで投影法は球体メルカトル、地点の座標はWGS84というWebでありがちなパターンです。
WGS84をメルカトルにtransfromした座標を使えば地図の上にマーカーを打つことができます。
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/ に豊富な例があるのでこんな拙いプログラムが無くてもそれを読めばたいていのことはわかりますが。

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="ol.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="map">
</div>
</body>
<script>
var map_ele = document.getElementById('map');

var view = new ol.View({
//      center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 10
});
var map = new ol.Map({
        view: view,
        layers:[
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                        name :'Base layer by OSM',
                        source : new ol.source.MapQuest({layer:'osm'})
                })
        ],
        target: map_ele
});

var mtfuji = [ 138.730883, 35.362859 ]; //富士山三角点 in WGS84
var pos = ol.proj.transform(mtfuji, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
view.setCenter(pos);

var point = new ol.geom.Point(pos, 'XY');
var pointer = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: point
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                anchor: [0.5, 1],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                opacity: 0.85,
                src: 'data/marker.png'
        })
})

pointer.setStyle(iconStyle);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [pointer]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
記述していただいたソースをそのまま実行したら確かにPointの示す位置にマーカーが表示されました。
しかし、var mtfuji以下の処理を自分のソースに当てはめても何故かマーカーは[0,0]の位置を指していました。
しかし、方法的には間違えていないと認識できたので、違う観点で調べてみます。
「WGS84をメルカトルにtransfromした座標を使えば地図の上にマーカーを打つことができます。」とのことですが、自分の示したソースではmap.getView().getCenter(); で coordinateを取得しているのでtransformは不要なはずです。